# Converting Select and Update into Update with SubSelect in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a select query as below:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 
FROM 
(
    SELECT A.COL1, B.COL2, A.COL3 
    FROM 
    SCHEMA1.TAB1 A, SCHEMA2.TAB2 B 
    WHERE 
    A.SOMECOL = B.SOMECOL 
) TEMP 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM SCHEMA3.TAB3 C WHERE C.COL3 = TEMP.COL3
)
```

Now in my current code setup, I am running the `SELECT` first to get the results and then in the next step, I am updating table `SCHEMA3.TAB3` with below update query by iterating through the result set:

```
UPDATE SCHEMA3.TAB3 SET COL1=?, COL2=? WHERE COL3=?
```

Where the three parameter values are coming from the result of above `SELECT`.

But, now I want to convert this two steps of selecting and updating into a single update statement with a sub select and do away completely with parameter setting.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Something does not compute here. You are selecting from TAB1 the rows where COL3 is not present in TAB3; how are you planning to update in TAB3 the rows that do not exist there?

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to be wrong with your question.

You are updating where `TAB3.COL3 = TAB1.COL3`, but in the original `SELECT` to obtain the values you have eliminated the rows where `TAB3.COL3 = TAB1.COL3`.